# How to get the links visited by Webview?

Tags: android, webview

I want to get the links visited by a webview in my android app.
More clearly,If my link be example.com and there is a hyperlink inside that webpage. If the user clicks the link, I want to toast the same link.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "onPageStarted: " + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Based on the documentation at:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#basic-usage
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)